# creating a bcd squarer using verilog

Tags: verilog, xilinx, hdl, binary, square

Basically, I am using a lookup table to output in bcd the square of a single digit bcd.

The problem that I have is that it is not outputting the correct answer.

For example: the result I get for the square of these number are:

1 = 1

2 = 4

4 = 10

5 = 19

10 = 64

as you can see I have to separate MBCD and LBCD and then concatenate them.

Here is my code:

```
module bcdsquarer(input[3:0]bcdin, output[7:4]Mbcd, output[3:0]Lbcd);
parameter msb = 16;
parameter lsb = 8;
reg [lsb-1:0]ROM[0:msb-1];
integer i;
initial 
    begin
    for(i=0; i<16; i = i+1)
        begin
            ROM[i] = i**2;
        end
    end
    assign {Mbcd,Lbcd} = ROM[bcdin];
endmodule
```

do anyone see where I made a mistake at?

edit:
Okay, So know I have to convert from binary to bcd. I have a code that converts, but how do I implement it with my bcdsquarer?

here is my code

```
module B2BCD(B,hundreds,tens,ones);
    input [7:0] B;
    output [3:0] hundreds;
    output [3:0] tens;
    output [3:0] ones;
    integer x;
    reg [3:0] hundreds, tens, ones;
    always @(B)
    begin
        x=B;
       hundreds=0; tens=0; ones = 0;
       if(x>99)begin hundreds =hundreds +1; x =x-100; end
       if(x>99)begin hundreds =hundreds +1; x =x-100; end
       repeat(9)
       begin
       if(x>9)begin tens = tens +1; x =x-10; end
       end

       ones =x;
    end
endmodule
```

I tried implementing it like this: (I just get x for my results now)

```
module bcdsquarer(bcdin,Mbcd,Lbcd,tens,ones);
parameter msb = 16;
parameter lsb = 8;

input[3:0]bcdin;

output[7:4]Mbcd;
output[3:0]Lbcd;

output [3:0] tens;
output [3:0] ones;

integer x;
reg[3:0] tens;
reg[3:0] ones;
    always @(bcdin)
    begin
        x=bcdin;
       tens=0; ones = 0;
       begin
       if(x>9)begin tens = tens +1; x =x-10; end
       end

       ones =x;
    end

assign Mbcd = tens;
assign Lbcd = ones;

reg [lsb-1:0]ROM[0:msb-1];
integer i;
initial 
    begin
    for(i=0; i<16; i = i+1)
        begin
            ROM[i] = i**2;
        end
    end
    assign {Mbcd,Lbcd} = ROM[bcdin];
endmodule
```

Comment: Why not simply pre-compute the contents of the ROM and either initialise it from a file, or by bit-slicing a parameter?

Comment: I am barely learning verilog. I need to use a lookup table for this.

Comment: So use a look up table. But use a calculator (or excel) to work out what all the values are, and simply initialise the LUT with that data.

Comment: The answer to "why are the values wrong" is simply that the result of ```i**2``` is in binary. Splitting the nibbles does not convert binary to BCD.

Comment: I thought I was already using a lookup table.

Comment: ohhh I see. So I have to convert.

Comment: just curious, is there any fast way to make it BCD instead of binary?

Comment: Precompute the values. That's the fast way...

Answer (score 2):

Basically Verilog operations are done in *binary* not *BCD*. So if you do something like `i**2` the result will be in binary. Splitting the nibbles doesn't convert binary to BCD.

You have two options. Either:

1. Continue and implement a binary to BCD conversion - you could do this as a function, which because it is used in an initial block shouldn't infer any hardware assuming it is something the synthesizer can calculate. Or
2. Compute all the values before hand, and simply initialise the LUT you have designed with the precomputed values. This is by far the easiest way, and to be honest likely (or so I've found) the usual way of doing it.

In the latter option you can do this several ways. One is to use something like Excel to compute a table of values and initialise the LUT from that - e.g. by reading the values in turn from a file (Verilog has macros for this like $readmem).

Alternatively if you are feeling adventurous, you can create a script (e.g. TCL) which creates the values and generates either the a Verilog file containing the code for the whole LUT including initialation, or creates a memory initialisation file which you can load into your LUT. This option is not really useful for this particular example, but great for more complex ones, perhaps save it for once you've gained more experience.

Comment: I like these suggestions. Thank you. Unfortunately, I have yet learn to read in a file. So, I don't think I could go that route. I would have to do option 1. Check my edit. I have a code for converting binary to bcd but I don't know how I would add it into my existing code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a code that is similar that I used for single digits squared (0-9).

```
module squarer(
input [3:0] B,
output [7:0] SQ
);

localparam NL=16;
localparam Nb=8;
reg [Nb-1:0]ROM [0:NL-1];
integer i;
initial
begin

ROM[0]=8'b0000_0000;
ROM[1]=8'b0000_0001;
ROM[2]=8'b0000_0100;
ROM[3]=8'b0000_1001;
ROM[4]=8'b0001_0110;
ROM[5]=8'b0010_0101;
ROM[6]=8'b0011_0110;
ROM[7]=8'b0100_1001;
ROM[8]=8'b0110_0100;
ROM[9]=8'b1000_0001;

end
assign SQ=ROM[B];
endmodule
```

The simulation code was:

```
module testsq;
reg [3:0] B;
wire [7:0] SQ;

squarer uut (
    .B(B), 
    .SQ(SQ)
);

initial begin
B = 0;

#10  B = 0;
#10  B = 1;
#10  B = 2;
#10  B = 3;
#10  B = 4;
#10  B = 5;
#10  B = 6;
#10  B = 7;
#10  B = 8;
#10  B = 9;

#10 $finish;
end

endmodule
```

This gave the correct values for 0-9, 0=00, 1=01, 2=04, 3=09, 4=16, 5=25... 9=81.
Hope this helps, not sure if it exactly answers the question.

Comment: Yes. Something like this. btw I tried running it and it gave the wrong answer for the square of 4 and so on. Also, I want it to make it so the there are two parts to the answer. For example, the square of 4 is 16 (ROM[4]=8'b0001_0110). I want to display 0001 and 0110 separately.